# Modificar fonte padrão

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8-1

É possível modificar a fonte padrão de minha aplicação WindowsPhone 8.1?

Pois faço a alteração fonte, dentro do Visual Studio fica a fonte que escolhi, porém quando executo no aparelho a fonte que esta é a padrão.

```
   <HyperlinkButton Content="Teste" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="126,299,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="48" FontFamily="Pristina">
        ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somente algumas UI Fontes são suportadas diretamente no windows phone e a disponibilidade de cada fonte depende de qual idiomas de exibição são incluídos no dispositivo.

[Windows Phone Fonts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202920(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_WindowsPhonefonts) - neste link existe uma tabela detalhando quais as fontes suportadas

Existe também a possibilidade de incluir uma font "embed" no app utilizando o formato .\DirFonte\ArquivoFonte.ttf#NomeFonte

```
<HyperlinkButton Content="Teste" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="126,299,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="48" FontFamily="/Fonts/Comic.ttf#Comic">
```